# PHP Access Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have an HTML page where I have:

```
<script>
x = "Success";
</script>
```

If I go into Chrome DevTools and run `console.log(window.x)` it will return "Success" as it should.

When I add the following code:

```
<?php
echo "<script>console.log(window.x)</script>";
?>
```

I get `undefined` in the Console.

Is there a way to access the `window.x` variable from PHP?

Comment: Works fine on my side, is the JS and PHP scripts on the same file?

Comment: You'd get `undefined` if that code runs before `x` is set. I hope you know that this isn't accessing a variable "from PHP". It's just generating HTML that is evaluated by the browser.

Comment: That code, in that order, on a given page, won't give the result you describe. There must be an issue with the way you are combining the two bits of code, but you need to show us how you are trying to do that in a single example.

Comment: you can't......................................................

Comment: @NewbeeDev — Can't what? Do what the question title says in a trivial way? Well, yes, but (a) there are ways to deal with that and (b) you don't seem to have read the main body of the text of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its output is `undefined` because variable `x` was not set in your **PHP** code.And this is just simple **HTML** print its not converting **JS** variable into **PHP**.

**Try with:**

```
echo "<script>x='success';console.log(window.x)</script>";
```

**[See OUTPUT here.](http://phpio.net/s/8x8)**

Comment: "Its output is undefined because variable x was not set in your PHP code" — That doesn't matter. The PHP code is just generating (as far as it is concerned) text. The `x` is only interpreted as a variable once it gets to the JavaScript engine.

Comment: @Quentin Are you sure that doesn't matter?
Please tell me what he want to do? What you understand from the question?

Comment: "Are you sure that doesn't matter?" — Yes. There is no way it can matter.

Comment: "Please tell me what he want to do?" — The problem is not clear (although it is clear enough to tell that this answer is wrong), that is why I made a comment on the question seeking clarification.

Comment: I'm sure Quentin is only criticizing how you phrased the first sentence. You are saying yourself that the PHP code just prints HTML, so saying that *"because variable x was not set in your PHP code."* is confusing at best and wrong at worst. You are not setting the variable in PHP either, all you do is change the value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

All PHP is executed server side so when you echo out a script like that you are just constructing HTML using PHP. In other words PHP is not able to interpret JavaScript, only a browser is.

I assume you have the PHP echo statement at the top of the page and the script block that defines "x" below it, like this:

```
<?php
echo "<script>console.log(window.x)</script>";
?>
<script>
x = "Success";
</script>
```

So in essence this is what you get:

```
<script>
console.log(window.x);
x = "Success";
</script>
```

Clearly "x" is undefined at the time you send it to the console. But if you move your PHP code below the line "x = "Success";", then your console will show what you expect.

However none of this addresses your real question: How do I get the value of a JavaScript variable into PHP?

There are three ways to accomplish that, AJAX, a form submission or use a headless browser.

Remember PHP is all server side and JavaScript is all client side. That means you have to send JavaScript to a client browser, let the browser execute your JavaScript logic and use POST / GET to send the variable back to the server for PHP to use.

Here is a simple HTML form that send the value of "x" to the server:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" id="xValue" name="valueOfX" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Send to Server">
</form>

<script>
var x = "Success";
document.getElementById('xValue').value = x;
</script>
```

When the server receives the POST from your form, you will see the value of "x" as:

```
$_POST["valueOfX"]  = "someValue"
```

You can avoid having to click the submit button by using AJAX. The key lesson is PHP is server side, JavaScript is client side.

This last part is VERY likely outside the scope of what you are trying to do, but it might help you else where. The headless PHP browser

Here is a project that gives PHP access to a browser: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS.

This project sets up a real browser process on your server running PHP. Then you can ask it to open the webpage and get the element you need (in the example the element has id=xValue):

```
$myUrl          = "http://www.example.com/myPage.php";
$windowObj      = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs')->getNewWindow($myUrl);

$selector   = "[id=xValue]";
$eleDetails = $windowObj->getElement($selector);
```

$eleDetails has, among other attributes, the value you want in a nice PHP array.